# How can I run a JAR file on Amazon EMR which is created using Hadoop 2.7.5?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I found that Amazon EMR has changed it's hadoop version from 2.7.3 to 2.8.3 and there is no option for 2.7.5. Now, I am using custom jar which is created using hadoop 2.7.5. Is there any way to run that JAR on Amazon EMR? The cluster is terminating with error while I am trying to run that jar using existing EMR version (either with hadoop 2.7.3 or 2.8.3) which is logical.

Comment: I suggest you recompile the code or downgrade back to 2.7.3, which should be able to run most 2.7.5 code

Comment: Amazon keeps all its EMR versions intact. All you need to do while lauching a EMR job is specify the release lable. E.g. for 2.7.3, I use emr-5.11.0 . Here is detailed info  :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/images/emr-releases-5x.png